# What is the minting cost of an NFT?

Tags: nft, fee, minting

What is the minting cost of an NFT? If it depends on some factors, can they be made explicit?

Answer (score 1):

All fees on Cardano are deterministic, so you'll always know the cost of the tx before you submit it. NFTs usually have metadata, depending on the amount of metadata included in the NFT will be factored into the fee and presented to you.

This article goes into detail on how the fee is calculated, keep in mind that the metadata size while reading this.
https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2017/10/19/how-cardanos-transaction-fees-work/